# Store Completion Handler in Variable iOS (Objective c)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to do a repeating task with the result of an http request and so would like to store the declaration of the completion hander in a variable (or somehow declare it as a function that can be passed in).

Example code:

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
   // carry out some action
 }];
```

I would like to be able to write

```
   [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler: standardHandler ];
```

Where *standardHandler* contains a block function.

Is this possible?

I'm quite new to Objective C so sorry if this is an obvious question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure:

```
void (^completionHandler)(NSURLResponse *, NSData *, NSError *) = ^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    // carry out some action
};
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:completionHandler];
```

Comment: I like the URL of the website! :) Thanks for the info, i'll accept the answer as soon as it lets me!